# Поворот одного элемента в сторону другого элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как вычислить угол поворота элемента A к элементу B?

**http://jsfiddle.net/ugczc1vs/**

HTML

```
<div id="place">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#place {
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

#a,
#b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background: red;
}

#b {
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    background: green;
}
```

JavaScript

```
/*

var a = [ 30, 30 ];
var b = [ 200, 200 ];

var angle = ???;

$('#a').css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
});

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы бы получше объяснили, например, если вы планируете поворачивать элементы с помощью jquery.

```
$('#a').on('click', function(){
    $('#a').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(10deg)'
    });
});
```

В таком случае сохраняйте куда-нибудь в переменную или `$('#a').attr('data-rotate', '10');`.
Ну а дальше математика и всё!